# Can I create an array of song and use the shuffle() method for it?

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi can I have and array of int[] music = {R.raw.song1, R.raw.song2}
and use the music.shuffle() ? so that I will put this method in the next button for it to shuffles to a random songs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this helps

```
private int getRandomSong(int[]  music) {
    int max = music.length - 1;
    int min = 0;
    int random = (new Random()).nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    return music[random];
}
```

happy coding :)

next time try to give a bit more information about the question else you will get down votes unnecessarily :)